# How to use UnsafeMutablePointer<T?> in swift 3

Tags: swift, swift-playground

I'm new to Swift and i don't understand how to use `UnsafeMutablePointer<T?>`. Could anyone help me?

```
struct TestStruct {
    var a = 0
}

func foo(ptr: UnsafeMutablePointer<TestStruct?>?) {
    ptr?.pointee?.a = 123 // pointee is nil, but why?
}

func bar(ptr: TestStruct?) {
    print("hello: \(ptr?.a)") // hello: nil
}

var ref = UnsafeMutablePointer<TestStruct?>.allocate(capacity: 1)

foo(ptr: ref)
bar(ptr: ref.pointee)

ref.deallocate(capacity: 1)
```

I'm allocate memory for the `TestStruct`, but when i pass `ref` to the `foo`, `pointee` points to the `nil`. If i will make `TestStruct` ( `UnsafeMutablePointer<TestStruct>` ) non-optional - everything will work great - bar prints `hello: 123`.

**UPDATE:**

Thanks to the @MartinR and @Hamish ! Working code:

```
struct TestStruct {
    var a = 0
}

func foo(ptr: UnsafeMutablePointer<TestStruct?>?) {
    ptr?.pointee?.a = 123
}

func bar(ptr: TestStruct?) {
    print("hello: \(ptr?.a)")
}

var ref = UnsafeMutablePointer<TestStruct?>.allocate(capacity: 1)

ref.initialize(to: TestStruct())

foo(ptr: ref)
bar(ptr: ref.pointee)


ref.deinitialize()
ref.deallocate(capacity: 1)
```

Comment: I have run your code and get the output `hello: Optional(123)`.

Comment: @MartinR did you run it in a playground?

Comment: @MartinR Swift 3.0.2 and OS X 10.12.3

Comment: Indeed, I can reproduce it in a Playground. It runs as expected in a compiled project.

Comment: @Alexey Don't test it in a playground, they're notoriously buggy and unreliable – always test code in a real project. Although that being said, I wouldn't expect your code to run in a reliable way anyway. You never initialize `ref`'s `pointee`, so it could hold some garbage value for all you know, therefore there's no knowing what will happen when you say `pointee?.a = ...`. You need to initialise the `pointee` to something first.

Comment: @MartinR i've restart Playground project and got `hello: Optional(123)` , but when i've added `print("\(ref.pointee?.a)")` after `bar(ptr: ref.pointee)` i again received a nil... Is this normal Playground behaviour?

Comment: @Alexey: As Hamish said (while I was writing the answer), the behaviour of your program is *undefined.* It may work or not. You have to initialize the memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behaviour of your program is undefined.

`allocate()` returns *uninitialized* memory:

```
/// Allocates and points at uninitialized aligned memory for `count`
/// instances of `Pointee`.
///
/// - Postcondition: The pointee is allocated, but not initialized.
public static func allocate(capacity count: Int) -> UnsafeMutablePointer<Pointee>
```

You have to initialize it before use
(and deinitialize before freeing the memory):

```
let ref = UnsafeMutablePointer<TestStruct?>.allocate(capacity: 1)
ref.initialize(to: TestStruct())

foo(ptr: ref)
bar(ptr: ref.pointee)

ref.deinitialize()
ref.deallocate(capacity: 1)
```

---

Here is another example where not initializing the memory actually 
leads to a crash:

```
class TestClass {
    init() { print("init") }
    deinit { print("deinit") }
}

let ptr = UnsafeMutablePointer<TestClass>.allocate(capacity: 1)
ptr.pointee = TestClass()
```

The assignment statement expects that `ptr.pointee` is in the initialized state
and points to a `TestClass` instance. Because of ARC (automatic
reference counting), the previously pointed-to object is *released*
when assigning a new value. That crashes if `ptr.pointee` is
uninitialized.